# How to make output of printf in one line

Tags: c

(Can't use space and can't use: if,switch,.....case)
I have my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dd, mm, yyyy;

    printf("Podaj date (w formacie dd-mm-yyyy):");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &dd, &mm, &yyyy);
    printf("Day:%02d\nMonth:%02d\nYear:%04d\n",dd,mm,yyyy);

    return 0;
}
```

And output looks like this:

```
Podaj date:06-08-0009
Day:06
Month:08
Year:0009
```

And how do it like this

```
Podaj date: 06-08-0009
Day:       06
Month:     08
Year:    0009
```

Comment: Add spaces in your `printf`?

Comment: @klutt: I don't think that actually applies since they also need leading zeroes here.

Comment: Please read the documentation of `printf()` or use a decent C book.

Comment: i can't add space, it's a rule, need to find another way

Comment: @Vladyslav: I don't believe there is a mechanism to do this in printf if you also need leading zeroes.

Comment: Read the doc! You might find `"%*s"` with an empty string (or a string with a single space) most vaulable. -- Oh, you need to know the number of spaces.

Comment: @Vladyslav If you cannot add space, then you should include that (and all other) requirements in your question.

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to format the numbers into strings, then print those strings in `%-<width>s` fields with appropriate widths.

Comment: https://ideone.com/EOOrMR or https://ideone.com/HtoyiG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the fixed parts of the format string as arguments instead and decide on the width of each in the format string:

```
printf("%-11s%02d\n%-11s%02d\n%-9s%04d\n", "Day:", dd, "Month:", mm, "Year:", yyyy);
//       ^^^        ^^^        ^^^
//        |          |        "Year:"
//        |         "Month:"
//        |
//       "Day:" - left adjusted, 11 chars
```

Also, always check that `scanf` succeeds:

```
if(scanf("%d-%d-%d", &dd, &mm, &yyyy) == 3) {
    printf("%-11s%02d\n%-11s%02d\n%-9s%04d\n", "Day:", dd, "Month:", mm, "Year:", yyyy);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god,love u, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
void scanAndPrint(unsigned nspaces)
{
    int dd, mm, yyyy;

    printf("Podaj date (w formacie dd-mm-yyyy):");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &dd, &mm, &yyyy);
    printf("\nDay:%*s%02d\nMonth:%*s%02d\nYear:%*s%04d\n", nspaces - 2 - (int)sizeof("DAY"),"", dd,nspaces - 2 - (int)sizeof("MONTH"),"", mm,nspaces - 4 - (int)sizeof("YEAR"),"", yyyy);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kj1aoEazb